# MVC Model Binding Dynamic Types using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I currently have a working solution but it is quite messy and trying to find a better way to accomplish my task.

I have an entity model which is used across multiple databases but each database has a few tables that have their schema customized on a case by case basis.

How can I cleanly implement MVC model binding from dynamic types generated at runtime based on database definitions?

In a nutshell in my working, but messy code, I have a model (when simplified) looks like this:

```
public class Actor
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public UserDefinedFields Udfs { get; set; }
}

public class UserDefinedFields
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ActorId {get; set;}
}
```

In my application, there are multiple databases and for each database user-defined fields has a different schema.

For example:

```
Create Table [Database1].[dbo].[UserDefinedFields]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY,
    [ActorId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES ACTOR(ID),
    [PurchaserID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BrandName] [varchar](100) NULL,
)
```

and:

```
Create Table [Database2].[dbo].[UserDefinedFields]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY,
    [ActorId] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES ACTOR(ID),
    [TotalUnits] [int] NULL,
    [TotalPriceRounded] [int] NULL,
)
```

My controller takes an `ActorViewModel` as a parameter bound with an `IModelBinder`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(int CaseId, Guid FormId, [ModelBinder(typeof(ActorModelBinder))] ActorViewModel actorViewModel)
{
    // Validation logic.
    actorViewModel.Save();
    return View(actorViewModel);
}
```

Now in my `ActorModelBinder` I have to start jumping through hoops.

```
public class CASClaimViewModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        IValueProvider provider = bindingContext.ValueProvider;
        ActorViewModel model = new ActorViewModel();
        BindModel();
        return model;
    }
}
```

In this constructor of `ActorViewModel` a `DynamicDbContext` derived from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` is created:

```
DynamicDbContext ctx = null;
UserDefinedFields udfs =null;

public ActorViewModel()
{
   ctx = DbContextFactory.GetContext();
   udfs = ctx.CreateUserDefinedFieldsInstance();  
}
```

`DynamicDbContext` is derived from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` and under the hood `DbContextFactory.GetContext` loads a base EDMX model and adds the types in the base model to the `DynamicDbContext`.

`DynamicDbContext` is actually part of a semi-large stand along class library that I created that has numerous classes, type builders, and other methods to dynamically read any given EDMX model and dynamically compiling and entity model. It is basically reinventing the wheel on a portion of Entity Framework so that instead of generating a static entity model one time, it will create an entity model on the fly at run time from any database it is given a connection string to.

Hence, it connects to the database and reads the column definitions of the customized `UserDefinedFields` table for that database, along with any other tables that I have marked as a `DynamicEntity` in the EDMX model.

I then use `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder` to dynamically create a dynamic `UserDefinedFields` type and add it the `DynamicDbContext`.

`ctx.CreateUserDefinedFieldsInstance()` creates an instance of dynamic `UserDefinedFields` type created by the type builder and returns it.

In the `BindModel()` method I need to create a `List<ModelBindingTarget>` and loop through each one and manually bind properties of my model to values in `Request.Form`.

```
List<ModelBindingTarget> bindingTargets = new List<ModelBindingTarget>()
{
    new ModelBindingTarget() { TargetType = typeof(Actor), Prefix= Constants.ActorPrefix , Instance = model.Actor } ,
    new ModelBindingTarget() { TargetType = model.Claim.UDFs.GetType(),  Prefix= Constants.UDFPrefix, Instance = model.Actor.UDFs  } ,
    // actual model is much more complex and all of the custom types in the model need to be bound.
};
bindingTargets.ForEach(x => BindFromForm(x));
```

`BindFromForm` loops through all the Keys in `Request.Form`. ForEach one of those keys it checks if a property exists in the model with a name and path matching the key and when finding a property name that matches a form key it sets the property.

```
foreach (ModelBindingTarget target in bindingTargets)
{
    string prefix = target.Prefix;

    if (!target.TargetType.IsGenericType)
    {
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in target.Instance.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string formkey = prefix + prop.Name;
            var val = provider.GetValue(formkey);

            if (val != null && val.AttemptedValue != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                    {
                        if (val.AttemptedValue == Constants.On || val.AttemptedValue == Constants.One || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.True, true) == 0 || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.Y, true) == 0)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(target.Instance, true);
                        }
                        else if (val.AttemptedValue == Constants.Zero || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.False, true) == 0 || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.N, true) == 0)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(target.Instance, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(target.Instance, val.ConvertTo(prop.PropertyType));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(target.Instance, val.ConvertTo(prop.PropertyType));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not value of '" + val.AttemptedValue + "' for" + formkey + " to type " + prop.PropertyType.ToString(), ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

        foreach (string key in Form.Keys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith(prefix))
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(key.Substring(prefix.Length).Split("]".ToCharArray())[0]);

                if (!indexes.Contains(index))
                {
                    indexes.Add(index);
                }
            }
        }

        if (indexes.Count == 0) 
            continue;

        indexes.Sort();
        Type InstanceType = null;
        string instanceTypeName = target.Instance.GetType().Name;

        if (instanceTypeName == "TransactionDetails")
        {
            InstanceType = typeof(TransactionDetail);
        }
        else if (instanceTypeName == "UserDefinedRow")
        {
            InstanceType = model.GetUDRType();
        }
        else
        {
            InstanceType = model.GetTypeFromGeneric(target);
        }

        System.Collections.IList list = target.Instance as System.Collections.IList;

        foreach (int index in indexes)
        {
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(InstanceType);

            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in InstanceType.GetProperties())
            {
                string formkey = prefix + index.ToString() + "]." + prop.Name;
                var val = provider.GetValue(formkey);

                if (val != null && val.AttemptedValue != null)
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                    {
                        if (val.AttemptedValue == Constants.On || val.AttemptedValue == Constants.One || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.True, true) == 0 || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.Y, true) == 0)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(instance, true);
                        }
                        else if (val.AttemptedValue == Constants.Zero || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.False, true) == 0 || string.Compare(val.AttemptedValue, Constants.N, true) == 0)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(instance, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(instance, val.ConvertTo(prop.PropertyType));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(instance, val.ConvertTo(prop.PropertyType));
                    }
                }
            }

            list.Add(instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if that isn't messy enough making matters worse is updating and existing entity requires jumping through even more hoops.

The bound model needs to be compared to and existing `DbEntity` and update changed properties as necessary and saved back into the database.